# How to use jQuery Ajax to refresh a php include?

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has all the variables parsing to an include. The first page does all the DB requests and passes the variables to the include. Our cloud framework means that we can't access files directly from the web but I can include them directly.

Example

```
get_responses($platform_id, $platform_name, $gettab, 10, $redirect, $redirecttab, $id, "1");
```

Calls the following function

```
function get_responses($platform_id, $platform_name, $type, $number, $redirect, $redirecttab, $challenge = "", $type_no){
 $api_url = datasepia('api:url');
$api_id = datasepia('api:id');
$api_key = datasepia('api:key');

$usr_name = "";
$usr_key = "";


XYZ below...
```

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty hard to help you due to you not give us any info specific on "your system",
you said us things about your cdn api .. but it's the less usefull thing we need to know

so i'll assume you not know what to do, here is a general way

> Our cloud framework means that we can't access files directly from the
>   web but I can include them directly.

so you just need a php wrapper to call these "includes" and get your data

```
<?php
    // read your args and if need sanitize them
    $id = $_POST['link']; // read your args

    // do the job and get/generate your data
    $mydata = get_responses($id, ... your api ... );

    //if you need json or anything else, it's now
    $mydata = json_encode($mydata);

    // here print/die the data
    die($mydata); // echo and return
?>
```

on the javascript side, you will call the wrapper with the needed informations,
depending on from where you launch the event and you store the needed info

here for an example i'll assume it's called on click on classic anchor tags and use href as args for your script

html :

```
<a href="/page2">my page 2</a>
```

jQuery :

```
// catch all anchor click
$(document).on('click','a',function(event){
    var $this = $(this); // current clicked anchor as a jquery object
    var href = $this.attr('href'); // get the link href

    // construct your ajax args
    var ajaxArgs = { link:href, hello:"world" };

    /* made an ajax call by jQuery, here i use post, check jQuery documentation */
    $.post('/my_php_ajax_listener.php', ajaxArgs, function(dataReturnByPhp){
        /* if here ajax has terminated, do anything with the data,
         * here we will fill #content html node with the data, assume data is here pure html */
         $("#content").html(dataReturnByPhp);
    });

    event.preventDefault(); // no real click please
});
```

good luck

Comment: I would like to post more but it's kind of hard to without giving all the code out publically. Is there anyway to discuss this kind of thing in private?

Comment: just adapt your get data api to the ajax php wrapper, when it's ok you will get only javascript part to create, who is more able to be publicaly show